# Zend Framework 2 xampp to production server router issues

Tags: zend-framework, migration, xampp, zend-framework2, routes

My application is working properly on the xampp environment but after being uploaded to the unit testing server it's encountering an error.

Not Found

The requested URL /application/public/login was not found on this server.

module.config.php

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'login' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'         => '/login',
                'constraints'   => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults'   => array(
                    'controller' => 'loginController',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                        'process' => array(
                                'type'    => 'Segment',
                                'options' => array(
                                        'route'    => '/[:action]',
                                        'constraints' => array(
                                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                        ),
                                        'defaults' => array(
                                        ),
                                ),
                        ),
                ),                  
        ),
        'logout' => array(
            'type'  => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'     => "/logout",
                'defaults'  => array(
                    'controller'    => 'loginController',
                    'action'        => 'logout'
                )
            )
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: That's because your router has no `/application` declared. You have `/public[/:action]` declared and no more.

Comment: that router config is on another module

Comment: actually I've found the fix. I've just modified the apache httpd.conf to allow override

Answer (score 0):

1) The 'public' directory must be specified as the root directory in the file C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
# Once for all hosts 
NameVirtualHost *:80 

# For each host
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/SkeletonApplication/public"
   ServerName localhost.myapp
   <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/SkeletonApplication/public>
      AllowOverride All
      Order deny,allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from localhost
   </Directory>
   DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

2) In your file C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.myapp
```

3) In your browser:

```
http://localhost.myapp/login
```

4) Your 'login' route has type 'literal', not 'segment'. And without 'constraints'.